# HTML5 canvas fade background image to another image and back

Tags: jquery, image, background, fade

I am trying to fade an background image back and forth to make it appear as the images is glowing. The code i am using fades the image but it causes the first background to fade completely out before it shows the next background image one I am trying to make it fade in and out without having the background be blank for the short moment.

```
var currentPlay = 0;
var playImages = [];
playImages[0] = 'images/home/noglow.png';
playImages[1] = 'images/home/glow.png';

function changeImage() {

    currentPlay++;
    if (currentPlay > 1) currentPlay = 0;

    $('#theImageToGlow').fadeOut(500, function () {
        $('#theImageToGlow').css({
            'background-image': "url('" + playImages[currentPlay] + "')"
        });

    });
    $('#theImageToGlow').fadeIn(500);
    setTimeout(changeImage, 500);
}

<canvas id="theImageToGlow" ></canvas>
```

Comment: Hm strange ... there is no canvas, you don't show how the changeImage() is being called, you don't show the swapPlayImages() function ... and you did not explain _exactly_ what you want ... and now you expect someone to be able to help?

Comment: Sorry i missed somethings in the original post. I hope it is easier to understand now. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fadeOut() will always fade to 0 opacity. You should use .fadeTo() instead and set an appropriate destination opactiy as a parameter to it.